# How to evaluate expression in Resharper like IntellijIdea(Alt+F8)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, expression, resharper

I want to evaluate expression at run time  in debug mode of VS2012 I have Resharper8 installed.

IntellijIdea provides this functionality in JAVA Debug mode. In that we can select a meaning full code expression and Alt+f8.

Or In Eclipse We can have Debug > Display to evaluate expressions run time.

Anything available as a part of VS2010 or Resharper functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the watch window. Highlight the code, right click and select 'quick watch' or 'add watch'.

Comment: that wont allow me to test different expressions at run time against certain object state.

Comment: @jon-barker You are true hero. Thanks!